# When is using "sau-" for emphasis inappropriate?

Tags: prefix

How would you explain at what point using "sau-" for emphasis (z.B.: "Das ist saustark!") becomes somewhat offensive or vulgar with some word combinations?

Comment: Personally: never.  That's why this is a comment, and not an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The aggravating prefix "*sau-*" is considered as colloquial the most. You would not use it in other than a family or friends setting.

According to [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sau_) it is classified as rather strong (*"derb"*) when used with a negative connotation.

Therefore in most situations I recommend not to use it

Comment: OK @takkat dann bitte das politisch korrekte Synonym für "Sauwetter"

Comment: @bernd_k: "Miserables Wetter"?

Comment: @jonas akzeptabel im Gegensatz zu "Unwetter" was wohl nur von Nachrichtensprechern gebraucht wird, die nicht draußen und durchnässt sind

Comment: With appropriate family and friends, you wouldn't use it there too.

Comment: @bernd_k: ["Sauwetter: **salopp abwertend**"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sauwetter) = not recommended. Colloquial you could use *"Schmuddelwetter"*. In any other case simply say *"[sehr] schlechtes Wetter"*

Comment: @Takkat wenn du bis auf die Haut durchnässt noch von Schmuddelwetter sprichst, dann hast du eine ungewöhnlich gute Contenance.

Answer (score 9):

It is not so much inappropriate, but it sounds pretty cheap.

"Saustark" and "saugut" are the most common forms to use "Sau-". In some commercial contexts you can hear "saugünstig".

The forms where it isn't appropriate are "saudoof", "saudumm" and other combinations... where it is used to say "dumb like a pig".

Answer (score 6):

I can't think of any word combinations, where "sau-" would be considered vulgar. In some situations you might not use it because of its *very* informal register.